# How to display the list but without a certain item.

Tags: list, haskell

I have the following list, that contains a list of strings..
I have already searched the orginal list for the lists that contain the string "tom" and got the following list

```
[["leo", "tom"], ["meg", "tom"], ["George", "john", "adam", "tom"] ]
```

I now wish to display this list without "tom", i would do this through list comprehension but i don't know how to do that for a list that contains lists? Can someone help me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Writing this as a list comprehension would get complicated, I think. Easier to just chain simple functions.

```
-- Intended as l `without` x
without :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
without l x = filter (/= x) l

containing :: Eq a => [[a]] -> a -> [[a]]
containing l x = filter (x `elem`) l

listsWithTom = lists `containing` "tom"
listsMinusTom = map (`without` "tom") listsWithTom
```

Comment: okay so I have a function name that creates the original list, do i put these in the without and containing part?

Comment: Just replace `lists` with your input.

Answer (score 1):

```
notom xss = [[ x | x <- xs, x /= "tom"] | xs <- xss]
```

Or

```
notom = map (filter (/= "tom"))
```

Or in your particular case

```
notom = map init
```

Comment: okay great this is what i have been looking for, but if i already have a function how do i add this to the function?

Comment: @Dave5678, `notomFun = notom . fun`